# Simulate change does not seem to be tested well

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple react component. It has an `input` text field. I am testing it `onChange` function. But it is keep failing. Here is my component.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const handleSetSearch = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Enter search key"
        onChange={handleSetSearch}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the test.

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<App />", () => {
  const Wrapper = shallow(<App />);

  it("should call onChange function", () => {
    const input = Wrapper.find("input");
    expect(Wrapper.find('input').value).toEqual(undefined);
    Wrapper.find("input").simulate("change", {
      target: {
        name: "search",
        value: "Test"
      }
    });
    expect(Wrapper.find("input").value).toEqual("Test");
  });
});
```

This test returns following error.

```
Expected: "Test"
Received: undefined

      23 |      });
      24 |      console.log(Wrapper.find('input').prop('value'));
    > 25 |      expect(Wrapper.find('input').value).toEqual('Test');
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Here is the sandbox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-river-d0mj7?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: One thing the sandbox (and presumably your local IDE) shows you is that the `search` state value is currently _unused_... I'd also note that `"should call onChange function"` describes the _implementation_, not the _behaviour_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .prop()

```
it("should call onChange function", () => {
  const input = Wrapper.find("input");
  expect(input.value).toEqual(undefined);
  Wrapper.find("input").simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Test1' } })
  expect(Wrapper.find("input").prop('value')).toEqual("Test1");
});
```

Comment: It is still failing with that change.

Comment: Look at this [reproduced example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sinoussi-owr4y?file=/src/App.test.js)

Comment: The link you posted is empty. It does not have any tests and it does not have any usecase above I mentioned in my post.

Comment: You are right, I think I fixed it, try again pls https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-sinoussi-owr4y?file=/src/App.test.js

Comment: What did you fix in it? It is exactly the same as mine?